# How do I start memcached in the foreground with homebrew?

Tags: macos, memcached, homebrew, foreman

I installed memcached with homebrew and wish to start it in the foreground for use with the foreman gem. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. I'll post the answer now since I couldn't find it elsewhere.

`brew info memcached`

In the output look for something like:

> Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
>   /usr/local/opt/memcached/bin/memcached

Now just add this to your foreman procfile:

`memcached: /usr/local/opt/memcached/bin/memcached -vv`

Don't forget to add the `-vv` flag.

Thanks to this post for the help https://devnullity.wordpress.com/tag/memcached/